# Can't custom Tab bar native-base

Tags: native-base

I'm trying to custom the colors of my tab bar, but the colors aren't changing, I still have the default blue on my tab bar. 
I'm using the `2.1.5` version of `native-base`.

I followed the examples on the `V.2.0` documentation of native-base, used properties like `tabBarBackgroundColor` either on `<Tabs>` or `<Tab>` but got no results.

I have this code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Content, Tab, Tabs, Header, TabHeading, Icon, Text } from 'native-base';
import PageTwo from '../pages/PageTwo';

export default class PageThree extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
              <Header hasTabs/>
              <Tabs
               textStyle='#ED9D19'
               tabBarUnderlineStyle='#ED9D19'
               tabBarIconContainerStyle='#ED9D19'
               tabBarBackgroundColor='white'>
                  <Tab
                  tabBarBackgroundColor={{backgroundColor : '#ED9D19'}}
                   heading={ <TabHeading><Icon name="camera" /><Text>Camera</Text></TabHeading>}>
                    <PageTwo/>
                  </Tab>
                  <Tab heading={ <TabHeading><Text>No Icon</Text></TabHeading>}>

                  </Tab>
                  <Tab heading={ <TabHeading><Icon name="apps" /></TabHeading>}>

                  </Tab>
              </Tabs>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

As you can see, I tried to use different properties but no one seems to work, except for `tabBarPosition` which does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve my problem by bringing a theming file, as suggested in the documentation, here is my code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Content, Tab, Tabs, Header, TabHeading, Icon, Text, StyleProvider } from 'native-base';
import PageTwo from '../pages/PageTwo';
import getTheme from '../native-base-theme/components';
import commonColor from '../native-base-theme/variables/commonColor';

export default class PageThree extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <StyleProvider style={getTheme(commonColor)}>
            <Container>
              <Header hasTabs/>
              <Tabs>
                  <Tab heading={ <TabHeading><Icon name="camera" /><Text>Camera</Text></TabHeading>}>
                    <PageTwo/>
                  </Tab>
                  <Tab heading={ <TabHeading><Text>No Icon</Text></TabHeading>}>

                  </Tab>
                  <Tab heading={ <TabHeading><Icon name="apps" /></TabHeading>}>

                  </Tab>
              </Tabs>
            </Container>
          </StyleProvider>
        );
    }
}
```

Right now, I just have to change the values in the `commonColor.js` file that I need.

However, I still don't understand why I can't change the properties directly in my code...

Comment: Which variables did u change for tab color?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this and it worked for me , i have added backgroundColor to **TabHeading**  **style={{backgroundColor : '#1B2443'}}**

```
<Tab heading={<TabHeading style={{backgroundColor : '#1B2443'}}>
    <Text style={styles.textColor}>PRIVATE KEY</Text></TabHeading>}>
    <Text>Change tab color</Text>
</Tab>
```